# Get week numbers from month

Tags: python

Each month, I need to extract data from an API. However, I don't want data between the first and the last day of the month. I would like the data from each week belonging to the month.

For example, if I want to extract data from February 2023, I need the data from the weeks :

- 05 (30/01/2023 - 05/03/2023)
- 06 (06/02/2023 - 12/02/2023)
- 07 (13/02/2023 - 19/02/2023)
- 08 (20/02/2023 - 26/02/2023)

I looked in the datetime documentation, and online. I didn't find any ressources. I am not even sure a week number belongs officially to a month.

I am considering to write a code that calculate if 1st of a month is a Monday of a Tuesday, it's fine, but the 1st of a week is  Wednesday, Thursday, Friday or weekend, we have to look in the previous month.
In February for example, the 1st was a Wednesday, so the first week of the month starts at the last Monday of the previous month (January).

That's why I consider that week n°05 is in February.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want to do ?

Comment: You _did_ find `%U`, `%V` and `%W` or `isoweek`…? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday

Comment: Yup, that's not a problem to have these. I just wanted to know if there is a way to have the month number as a parameter, and then return a list of the week numbers. I can do that myself for sure, but I wanted to know if it already exists.

Comment: Start with the 1st of the month, then increment by a week until the end of the month…?

Comment: Yes, that's I'm going to do. The only tough part is that the last day of the month is not necessary a week I want (if it's a Monday or a Tuesday). I should be able to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You should go by existing "week" standards (of which there are different ones, see details of the `%U`, `%V`, `%W` tokens). If your definition doesn't fit any of the existing ones, then you should perhaps first consider adjusting *your* definition, and if that doesn't work, then yeah, you'll need to write custom code to implement *your* definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get week no. from current date using this python program

```
import datetime

# Get current date
today = datetime.datetime.today()

# Get week number (Sunday is considered the first day of the week)
week_number = today.strftime("%U")

print("Week number:", week_number)
```